# Consuming external json with parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on an iOS application developed with Swift. The application is going to need notifications to receive alerts when certain events occur.

To handle push notifications I'm using parse.com. I was able to create an account and integrate push notifications into my application, as it's explained in the Parse.com guide, and are working fine when I send something from the Push section.

What I'm trying to do, and I cannot figure it out, is consume a 3rd party JSON, process that JSON to check some status and report, to the users that are using the application, a status change via a push notification. I know I should process all this in the backend/server side and then push the result or what I'm trying to notify, but I don't know what to do.

Ex. of What I'm trying to archive:

> 3rd party website ---(json)---> parse.com ---(push notification)--->
>   My App

I'm aware the tools that Parse.com provides, such as **REST API**, **Cloud Code**, **Webhooks** and **Jobs**, but I'm totally lost here! I cannot find any guide or documentation that allows me to do what I previously described. I don't even know if its possible, and the documentation at parse.com it's not necesarily up to date.

I hope anyone can help me, or guide me, if parse.com it's not enought for my purpouse.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into Cloud Code or a Job from Parse and seeing if you can get one to run on a time interval to look for updated JSON.

You can decode JSON using JS, which is exactly what Parse Cloud Code is, you actually write it out on your own computer and then upload it. I've only use the afterSave functions. I would think you probably have to keep some type of object in parse to see what is updated and notify who ever needs to notified when that data is updated.

Also, you'll probably want to pass something to the app to actually update when the user selects the push alert. You can do this in the push alert itself. It converts to a dictionary in the app delegate's method for handling received notifications or launching with one.

Alternatively, if the web server is under your control, you can create a PHP script that will trigger the push to parse.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you helped me a lot! I wrote my own PHP Script and put it into my own server. It's working perfect!

Answer (score 1):

My best shot at this (after not having used Parse for a long while) would be to set up a Job on Parse that queries the 3rd-party service, and takes that response and throws it into a Cloud Code function, which in turn parses out that JSON and sends off a notification.

Parse's [reference materials](https://www.parse.com/docs) would probably be a good starting point.

The toughest part for you is the up-to-date-ness of your data. Since you're still polling that 3rd-party service at a regular interval, it's going to be a trade-off between freshness of updates and frequency of jobs (which cost money at a certain scale).